# How to model a molecule of benzene surrounded by 100 molecules of water with molecular dynamics?

Tags: computational-chemistry, intermolecular-forces, solvents, molecular-dynamics

I have experience calculating molecular properties (mostly DFT). However, I would like to spend some time on molecular dynamics methods. I would like to ask your advice to direct me towards a program with which to calculate systems such as the annealing of a benzene molecule surrounded by a hundred water molecules.

Comment: This question from matter modeling SE might be helpful: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6143

Comment: Do you mean simulated annealing? You can use Gromacs (https://www.gromacs.org/). Gromacs is quite easy to use. Also have a look at this post: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4341/finding-parameters-for-a-molecule-in-various-forcefields/4374#4374 I have done MD simulations of small molecules in gromacs, so I can write an answer on that if you want. I haven't done annealing so I can't really write about that.

Comment: Nisarg Bhavsar, thanks, I will dive a little bit into NAMD and see if I can get something running, I see there are some tutorials on youtube, for example, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IArpsQsZ95U seems good! Shoubhik R Maiti thank you for pointing out Gromacs, also here I could dive into maybe looking at some tutorials will be useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rYZ1p5lXNyc&t=1s.

Comment: @PaulPerkele In my personal experience, learning gromacs was easier than learning NAMD (in fact right now I am trying to learn that). However, you may find the other one easier. Yes youtube tutorials are helpful. Do keep in mind though that for small molecules, you usually get parameters/topology from servers like https://www.swissparam.ch/ or from softwares (because you need general forcefield). As an aside, if you are responding to a comment on this site, make sure to tag them with an @